# Hide and Show Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, show-hide, detach

[image]

I created **fragment-A** part of **Activity-A**, here I **HIDE fragment-A** and launch **fragment-B**, working fine. Now I detach **fragment-B**, so how **Fragment-A** come to know that now it's time to **wakeup** i.e. **SHOW**.

Answer (score 1):

use `addToBackStack` method which is `FragmentTransaction` class. The transaction will be remembered and when you press the back button while Fragment B is active, Fragment A will be shown.

Comment: This is better than my answer. Thanks, I've learned something new.

Comment: Actually it might not be enough if he has hidden fragment A... might need both this and overriding the onDetach() to unhide A.

Comment: If Activty A -> Activity B like transition is needed for Fragment A -> Fragment B, then dont hide Fragment A. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding

Comment: thanks for all info...I gave callback to fragment-A from onDetach(Fragment-B)..and call .show() for Fragment-A...it work for me...but I am more interested to know How can get top added Fragment from FragmentTransaction ?

Comment: If you want to retrieve any of the fragments added to the backstack you can do it by using methods 'findFragmentById()' or 'findFragmentByTag()' which are in FragmentManager class. However, if you want these methods to be effective you will have to assign a tag or id when adding a fragment using 'add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)' method.

Answer (score 0):

Override Fragment B's onDetach() method to unhide fragment A.

In case you need, this is a good guide on how to have fragments/activity interact with each other: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html